# List.Sum in Power Query is not ignoring null values

Tags: worksheet-function, power-query, microsoft-powerbi, dax, column

I added a column with this code:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Total Quantity", each List.Sum(
{[species_males]+[#"species_females-mixed"]

}))
```

List.Sum is supposed to ignore null values and return the sum of the remaining values, however, my column contains a null value in every row where one of the input columns had a null value:

[image: Column containing several null values]

How can I fix this and create a calculated column that ignores nulls?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. My mistake was using the plus sign. The correct code is:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Total Quantity", each List.Sum(
{[species_males],[#"species_females-mixed"]

}))
```